# The problem is "method' object is not iterable. I am doing a small Django app

Tags: json, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Here is the error when I go to employees page (employees is the model):

```
TypeError at /employees/
'method' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/employees/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'method' object is not iterable
Exception Location: C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py, line 677, in to_representation
Python Executable:  C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\USER\\PycharmProjects\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject1\\health_recommender_final',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\PycharmProjects\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject1\\health_recommender_final',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2021.1.1\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\PycharmProjects\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject1\\health_recommender_final\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\PycharmProjects\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject\\djangoProject1\\health_recommender_final\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2021.1.1\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Fri, 18 Jun 2021 01:49:34 +0000
```

My main files are serializers and models.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import Person


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        models = Person
        fields = '__all__'


from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Person(models.Model):
    EDUCATION_CHOICES = (
        ('NA', 'NONE'),
        ('SSC', 'SSC'),
        ('HSC', 'HSC'),
        ('undergraduate', 'UNDERGRADUATE'),
        ('graduate', 'POSTGRADUATE'),
        ('Further Studies or PhD', 'FURTHER/PhD'),
    )

    DIET = (
        ('Vegetarian', 'VEG'),
        ('Omnivore', 'OMNI'),
        ('Fish', 'FISH'),
    )

    EXERCISE = (
        ('na', 'NA'),
        ('yes', 'YES'),
        ('no', 'NO'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250,default="")
    education_details = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=EDUCATION_CHOICES, default='NA')
    diet = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=DIET, default='VEG')
    exercise = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=EXERCISE, default='NA')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-name',)

    @property
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So what should I do now? I think the method that is not iterable is coming because I left something out somewhere, where can it be?

I am trying to create a small app, which when taken has the above input as the model, which returns a JSON file. After that I would manipulate the JSON file with some programming to create health recommendations based on lifestyle choice. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong and how I can complete the JSON manipulation thing to get simple for - if submission things to create the recommendations??

```
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import Person
from .serializers import PersonSerializer
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import Person
from .serializers import PersonSerializer


class PersonList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        person1 = Person.objects.all
        serializer = PersonSerializer(person1, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self):
        pass
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

from healthrecomm import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('employees/', views.PersonList.as_view())


]


System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 18, 2021 - 07:49:18
Django version 3.2, using settings 'health_recommender_final.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[18/Jun/2021 07:49:34] "GET /employees HTTP/1.1" 301 0
Internal Server Error: /employees/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\healthrecomm\views.py", line 23, in get
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 760, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 260, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 677, in to_representation
    return [
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
[18/Jun/2021 07:49:34] "GET /employees/ HTTP/1.1" 500 105485
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[18/Jun/2021 07:49:35] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2123
C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject\djangoProject1\health_recommender_final\healthrecomm\models.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
```

Comment: you should also include your views in the post.

Comment: Can you replace the contents of the Django error page with the full traceback from the console/log in your question? Adding your view and urls would be useful too.

Comment: FYI: the `__str__` method on your model should not be a `@property`

Comment: use `Person.objects.all()` insted of `Person.objects.all`

Comment: Person.objects.all is a method which is not iterable itself, and you passed a method to serializer constructor instead of an iterable object.

Answer (score 2):

## views.py

The missing field is parenthesis in
`person1 = Person.objects.all`
() is missing

```
class PersonList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        # this person1 line is mistake ,
        person1 = Person.objects.all # this all()
        # ok ?                   ^^^
        serializer = PersonSerializer(person1, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self):
        pass
```

.
right is:
.

```
class PersonList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        # solution is this line
        person1 = Person.objects.all() # this all()
        # ok ?                   ^^^
        serializer = PersonSerializer(person1, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self):
        pass
```

it will fix the problem

Comment: I am very new to Django and this () fixed my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to Remove @property from Person model